# How to get Parent id while saving child object in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have two class as below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="KMACLM")
public class ClientTable 
{
    private int RID;
    private String ClientCode,ClientDesc;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="IMACLRID")
    public int getRID() {
        return RID;
    }
    @Column(name="IMACLCLC")
    public String getClientCode() {
        return ClientCode;
    }
    @Column(name="IMACLCLD")
    public String getClientDesc() {
        return ClientDesc;
    }
    public void setRID(int rID) {
        RID = rID;
    }
    public void setClientCode(String clientCode) {
        ClientCode = clientCode;
    }
    public void setClientDesc(String clientDesc) {
        ClientDesc = clientDesc;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "KMAPLM")
public class PlantTable {
    private Integer RID;
    private String PlantCode,PlantDescription,;
    private ClientTable ClientDetails;
    public void setClientDetails(ClientTable clientDetails) {
        ClientDetails = clientDetails;
    }
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "IMACLRID")
    public ClientTable getClientDetails() {
        return ClientDetails;
    }
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="IMAPLRID")
    public Integer getRID() {
        return RID;
    }
    @Column(name="UMAPLPTC")
    public String getPlantCode() {
        return PlantCode;
    }
    @Column(name="UMAPLPTD")
    public String getPlantDescription() {
        return PlantDescription;
    }
    public void setRID(Integer rID) {
        RID = rID;
    }
    public void setPlantCode(String plantCode) {
        PlantCode = plantCode;
    }
    public void setPlantDescription(String plantDescription) {
        PlantDescription = plantDescription;
    }
}
```

here comes the struts action.

```
Session s=null;
 Transaction t=null;    
try{

s=Hibernate_Common.getsessionfact().openSession();
t=s.beginTransaction();
ClientTable dd=new ClientTable();
dd.setClientCode(getClient());  //here i am setting client (Parent Element)

PlantTable Planttbobj=new PlantTable();
Planttbobj.setPlantCode(getPlantCode());
Planttbobj.setPlantDescription(getPlantDescription());
Planttbobj.setClientDetails(dd);
s.save(Planttbobj);
    t.commit();
    s.close();
}catch(Exception e)
{
    t.rollback();
    s.close();
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

i am getting the value from jsp and saving in database.

where i try to save the object every time the child element and parent element are inserted in the database.

**First time insertion**

```
IMACLRID    IMACLCLC    IMACLCLD
4           600         chennai

IMAPLRID    UMAPLPTC    UMAPLPTD    IMACLRID
3       7023        madurai     4
```

**Second time Insertion**

```
IMACLRID    IMACLCLC    IMACLCLD
4       600     chennai
5       600     chennai

IMAPLRID    UMAPLPTC    UMAPLPTD    IMACLRID
3       7023        madurai     4
4       7024        theni       5
```

where every time i try to inset a child a parent also inserting

duplicate values are inserted in parent table. plz help me!!!